# Группировать несколько элементов в группу (groupBox)

Tags: python, tkinter

Возможно ли в tkinter сгруппировать несколько элементов (кнопок, текстбокс, лабел) в одну группу, чтобы визуально была бы видна рамка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать компонент `LabelFrame` ([документация](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/labelframe.htm)). Пример кода:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()
label_frame = LabelFrame(root, text='Sample text')
label_frame.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

Entry(label_frame).pack(padx=5, pady=5)
Button(label_frame, text='Test').pack(padx=5, pady=5)

mainloop()
```

Скриншот (Windows 10):

[image: LabelFrame]

Скриншот (LinuxMint-18.1-xfce):

[image: LabelFrame Mint]

Также, если подпись к рамке не нужна, можно воспользоваться обычным `Frame` ([документация](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/frame.htm)), указав нужный рельеф (`SUNKEN`, `RAISED`, `GROOVE` или `RIDGE`, по-умолчанию `FLAT`). Однако, при использовании `tkinter.ttk` заметно, что рамка не использует настройки темы Windows:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root, relief=GROOVE)
frame.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

Entry(frame).pack(padx=5, pady=5)
Button(frame, text='Test').pack(padx=5, pady=5)

mainloop()
```

[image: Frame relief=GROOVE]

Под Linux также вид рамки вокруг `Frame` может отличаться от ожидаемого. Пример кода:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()

for relief in (FLAT, SUNKEN, RAISED, GROOVE, RIDGE):
    frame = Frame(root, relief=relief)
    frame.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

    Entry(frame).pack(padx=5, pady=5)
    Button(frame, text=relief).pack(padx=5, pady=5)

mainloop()
```

Скриншот:

[image: Все варианты рамки]

Видим, что groove по виду совпадает с raised, а ridge - с sunken.

Comment: Еще вопрос, при попытке написать в поле Entry не могу писать русскими символами, можно как-то исправить?

Comment: @fangry, у меня печатает нормально, не знаю в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: хм... возможно из-за линукса?

Comment: @fangry, проверил на LinuxMint 18.1 - нормально печатает.

Comment: Странно, ладно как-то решу. Возможно ли в Text заблокировать ввод текста со стороны пользователя?

Comment: @fangry, да, можно сделать его неактивным, но придется перед каждым выводом опять делать его активным, а потом опять блокировать. Если нужен пример, задайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60932/discussion-between-fangry-and-insolor).