# Python GUI . Что выбрать новичку?

Tags: python, gui, framework

Какой GUI фреймворк для Python выбрать новичку для создания приложений под windows ? Или же лучше начать с изучения стандартной библиотеки Tkinter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## PyQt5

PyQt5 довольно неплохое решение, может показаться сложным сначала, но потом, весьма логичным. В комплекте идёт QtDesigner - программа для создания графический окон.

---

Скачать: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/

Основы: https://tproger.ru/translations/python-gui-pyqt/

Comment: Подскажите еще кое-что. Слышал , что новичкам не следует браться за фреймворки, а изучать основы, принципы, и т.д. . Так ли это?

Comment: Изучать основы и принципы. Если у Вас некоторые трудности в понимании базы, с фреймворками пока повремените. Ткинтер, вообще, внимания новичка не стоит, как и Делфи, потому, что устарели. Просто сравните интерфейсы на ткинтере и qt. Конечно, это лишь моё мнение и Вам выбирать, прислушаться или нет.

Comment: @Евгений, вот не соглашусь по поводу Tkinter. На нем можно реализовывать вполне достойные интерфейсы, и не нужно тянуть с собой (если говорить про Windows) огромный Qt ради формочки с десятком элементов управления.

Comment: @AlekseiGrabor, для новичка главное пробовать. Если интересует веб - берите фреймворки. Если интересует десктоп - берите разные GUI библиотеки, пробуйте, разбирайтесь, смотрите минусы и плюсы. Параллельно (не до и не вместо вышеперечисленного) изучайте основы, алгоритмы, структуры данных, хотя бы ознакомительно. Берите интересные для себя задачи и пробуйте решать их.

Comment: @insolor, может Вы и правы и я смотрю со стороны линуксоида... И моё мнение ткинтере слижком уж предвзятое из-за отсутсвия лёгкого способа группировки эл-тов и среды визуального программирования которая бы хотя бы приближена к возможностям QtCreator/Designer... Да, я знаю про python-quickui...

Comment: @Евгений, среда визуального программирования - есть пара редакторов, но обычно пишу интерфейс руками. Редактора интерфейса, который бы меня устраивал, пока не нашел. Про группировку - есть `Frame` (с указанием рельефа границы), есть `LabelFrame` (см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/682677/1365). Или вы не про это?

Comment: @insolor, про лэйауты.

Comment: @Евгений, ну как бы `pack()`, `grid()` и `place()` хватает на все случаи жизни.

Comment: @insolor, ну... это уже мнения. Мы и так развели дискуссию, требуют переформулировать уже 2-ой день.