# Как сделать разделить на окна окно с помощью tkinter и python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примерно что бы выглядело вот так,смотрел везде не получается,помогите.

Comment: Можно обычный Frame использовать с включенным рельефом. Пример тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/682677/1365